# how can I use multiple ModelMetaDataProvider's w/asp.net-mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a custom ModelMetadataProvider which takes care of everything so far. But I have a couple of new classes where I am going to let users customize the metadata in the database and store settings like display name, sql query for combo's and some other stuff like that.

Well I am happy with my current ModelMetadataProvider, so I do not want to inject new functionality into it, I'd rather have a new ModelMetadataProvider for this, and a way of telling the !dependency resolver! to pick the right  data provider for a given class?

Is this possible, and if so how?
Thanks in advance...